# How to export a component attached to a component that uses React.forwardRef?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm building a UI system for input components and I'm looking to attach a component to another component that needs to use forwardRef. It normally works when the forwardRef isn't being used but I'm currently getting the error below. How can I resolve this error, or is exporting a function in a forwardedRef component not allowed?

Error:

```js
Property 'Secondary' does not exist on type 
'ForwardRefExoticComponent<ForwardedRefProps & RefAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>>'
```

Contrived Example

```js
interface ButtonProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {}

export const ForwardRefButton = React.forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, ButtonProps>(
  function Button(props, ref) {
    return(
      <button ref={ref}>Ref is forwarded</button>
    )
  }
)

ForwardRefButton.Secondary = function () { // <- ForwardRefButton.Secondary errors
  return (
    <button>Secondary Button</button>
  )
}
```